# New install of wordpress, my url goes to index of/

Tags: 404-error, installation

After my Wordpress installation (database hooked up and wp-config done and wp-login created).  I just get Index of/ page when I go to my URL. I uploaded all the contents of the Wordpress folder to the document-root of my Apache VirtualHost, after downloading it and unzipping.  Im taken to index of/ page for everything unless I specifically navigate to the page.. . I can get to the admin menu/dashboard (all admin stuff I can access). But there is nothing at my home URL. The site is labelleviemodesto.com. If i go there I get the index of/. If I try and go to labelleviemodesto.com/sample-page I get a 404 not found. What did I miss while installing? I made sure index.php is the first to be accessed in apache's dir.conf. I also noticed if I create a new page it cant be accessed either.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to create .htaccess file inside your site's home directory(like : /public_html)

Here is the sample :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And also check your files permission.  [See Details : Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess), 
Sometime wrong file permissions can creates this issues too.[See Details : Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

Comment: I made sure everything had the correct permissions and that my .htaccess file was good. Still the same problem. Idk if it would be affecting it, but the site is an apache virtualhost

Comment: how does your Apache httpd.conf looks like? can you print it here ? 
may be your haven't request Apache to serve index file. 
Example : 
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>